# Accessing object in array using string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have this code:

```
    var dictionary=[
            apple={name:"apple",pos:"noun",d:"",c:["fruit"]},
            banana={name:"banana",pos:"noun",d:"",c:["fruit"]}
    ];
```

How could I access one of the objects in the array by using a string of its name.  In the way that you could access an object as

```
     object['propertyName']
```

is there a way to do something similar with an array?  I want to access it in a way like

```
    dictionary["apple"].pos 
    //Want to return "noun"
```

Is there a simple way to do something like that with an array, and if not is there an alternative method that I could use?

Comment: Your array syntax is not correct. Check your code here http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: What part is not correct?  I didn't see any errors.

Comment: Well, I put the code in JSHint and it said "two undefined variables, `apple` and `banana`", not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're generating your `dictionary` s wrong; it's syntactically valid, but it's almost certainly *not* what you intended to do. It's not binding the key `apple` to that object. Rather, it's defining an implicit (global) variable named `apple` and assigning the object to that, as well as the first element of the array.

Try this:

```
var dictionary= {
    apple: {name:"apple",pos:"noun",d:"",c:["fruit"]},
    banana: {name:"banana",pos:"noun",d:"",c:["fruit"]}
};

console.log(dictionary["apple"].pos); // "noun"

// This also works:
console.log(dictionary.apple.pos);    // "noun"
```

Comment: You might want to also note in the post he doesn't need the redundant "name" property and he can also use dot syntax instead of a dict style `dictionary.apple.pos` (if he so chooses).

Comment: @Jay Good point. OP seems to be a bit new to JS, so he / she may not be familiar with that syntax.

Comment: The reason that I'm using the string is because I'm getting the properties by a user input box when a submit button is clicked, so the  dot syntax wouldn't really work in the context that I need.

Comment: @zchbrntmr: Yep, that's why you have to use bracket syntax.